# Generate Parent Sampler in a transaction controller

Tags: jmeter

I have checked-in 'Generate parent sample' for a transaction controller which has a few HTTP requests. Aggregate Report shows only the transaction controller name but Simple Data Writer report shows both the transaction controller name and the HTTP requests under that. Is there a way to see the Simple data writer with only the transaction controller names and not the HTTP requests underneath?
Thanks,
N

Answer (score 0):

Try running JMeter as:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false
```

if it produces the output you want - you can make the change permanent by adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false
```

More information:

- [Results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Even after adding the above line to the user.properties file, it shows all the child samples. Also, I checked the config options for both and both are exactly the same. Not sure why?